# Equivalent of Bash Backticks in Python

Tags: python, backticks

What is the equivalent of the backticks found in Ruby and Perl in Python? That is, in Ruby I can do this:

```
foo = `cat /tmp/baz`
```

What does the equivalent statement look like in Python? I've tried `os.system("cat /tmp/baz")` but that puts the result to standard out and returns to me the error code of that operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924310/whats-a-good-equivalent-to-pythons-subprocess-check-call-that-returns-the-conte

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
output = os.popen('cat /tmp/baz').read()
```

Comment: @mckenzm The question is about capturing the output of an external process. Capturing the output of a Python function would be a quite different question.

Comment: Wonderfully concise, and indeed the equivalent of Ruby's `\`...\`` (capturing stdout, passsing stderr through) - with one exception: Ruby allows determining the process' exit code via`$?`after the fact; in Python, from what I can tell, you'll have to use the `subprocess` module's functions for that.

Answer (score 85):

The most flexible way is to use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
import subprocess

out = subprocess.run(["cat", "/tmp/baz"], capture_output=True)
print("program output:", out)
```

`capture_output` was introduced in Python 3.7, for older versions the special function `check_output()` can be used instead:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["cat", "/tmp/baz"])
```

You can also manually construct a subprocess object if you need fine grained control:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/tmp/baz"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
```

All these functions support [keyword parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) to customize how exactly the subprocess is executed. You can for example use `shell=True` to execute the program through the shell, if you need things like file name expansions of `*`, but that comes with [limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).

Comment: yes, this is the only sane way, you could wrap it in a function so you can call something like execute("command")

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me, as in this case, baz is a directory and I'm trying to get the contents of all the files in that directory. (doing cat /tmp/baz/* works in ticks but not via the method described here)

Comment: re: "*" does not work; use subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/tmp/baz"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) instead. Since glob (star) expansion is handled by shell, subprocessing module must use shell expansion in this case (provided by /bin/sh).

Comment: you could use `subprocess.check_output()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236737/making-a-system-call-that-returns-the-stdout-output-as-a-string/236909#236909

Comment: From http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor : "(with shell=True) If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself." So, if you're going to use shell=True, then the first arg should probably be the string "cat /tmp/baz". Alternatively, if you want to use a sequence as the first arg then you should use shell=False

Comment: I thought the question was for the python equivalent of backticks. This seems more like the python equivelent of `IO.popen() {}`

Comment: @gerrit: it is not deprecated. The docs *recommend* `subprocess.run()` (I don't know whether it is deserved) if you don't need to support earlier versions or if you don't need the flexibility provided by `Popen()`.

Answer (score 28):

[sth is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410997/456814). You can also use os.popen(), but where available (Python 2.4+) subprocess is generally preferable.

However, unlike some languages that encourage it, it's generally considered bad form to spawn a subprocess where you can do the same job inside the language. It's slower, less reliable and platform-dependent. Your example would be better off as:

```
foo= open('/tmp/baz').read()
```

eta:

> baz is a directory and I'm trying to get the contents of all the files in that directory

? cat on a directory gets me an error.

If you want a list of files:

```
import os
foo= os.listdir('/tmp/baz')
```

If you want the contents of all files in a directory, something like:

```
contents= []
for leaf in os.listdir('/tmp/baz'):
    path= os.path.join('/tmp/baz', leaf)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        contents.append(open(path, 'rb').read())
foo= ''.join(contents)
```

or, if you can be sure there are no directories in there, you could fit it in a one-liner:

```
path= '/tmp/baz'
foo= ''.join(open(os.path.join(path, child), 'rb').read() for child in os.listdir(path))
```

Comment: Although this wasn't an answer to the question, it's the best answer for educating users.

Comment: The question title is "what is the equivalent of backticks". I assumed that "cat" was just an example command. This answer does not help with the general case.

Answer (score 16):

```
foo = subprocess.check_output(["cat", "/tmp/baz"])
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward way now. "subprocess.check_output" was added in Python 2.7, which was released in July 2010, after the other "popen" answers were given.

Answer (score 12):

From Python 3.5 onward, the recommended way is to use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).  Since Python 3.7, to get the same behaviour as you describe, you would use:

```
cpe = subprocess.run("ls", shell=True, capture_output=True)
```

This will return a `subprocess.CompletedProcess` object.  The output to stdout will be in `cpe.stdout`, the output to stderr will be in `cpe.stderr`, which will both be `bytes` objects.  You can decode the output to get a `str` object by using `cpe.stdout.decode()` or get a by passing `text=True` to `subprocess.run`:

```
cpe = subprocess.run("ls", shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

In the latter case, `cpe.stdout` and `cpe.stderr` are both `str` objects.

Comment: From python 3.7 on you can use the `text=True` parameter to get back a str instead of bytes.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way is to use commands package.

```
import commands

commands.getoutput("whoami")
```

Output:

> 'bganesan'

Comment: Very easy, but the module is now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
foo = os.popen('cat /tmp/baz', 'r').read()
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of Ruby's backticks, but if your problem is to list the contents of a directory then this is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using

> (6:0)$ python --version
>   Python 2.7.1

One of the examples above is:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/tmp/baz"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print "program output:", out
```

For me, this failed to access the directory /tmp.  After looking at the doc string for subprocess I replaced

> [ "prog", "arg"]

with

> "prog arg"

and got the shell expansion behavior that was desired (a la Perl's `prog arg`)

> print subprocess.Popen("ls -ld /tmp/v*", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]

---

I quit using python a while back because I was annoyed with the difficulty of of doing the equivalent of perl `cmd ...`.  I'm glad to find Python has made this reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

If you use subprocess.Popen, remember to specify bufsize. The default is 0, which means "unbuffered", not "choose a reasonable default".

Answer (score 1):

This will not work in python3, but in python2 you can extend `str` with a custom `__repr__` method that calls your shell command and returns it like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

class Command(str):
    """Call system commands"""

    def __repr__(cmd):
        return os.popen(cmd).read()
```

Which you can use like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from command import Command

who_i_am = `Command('whoami')`

# Or predeclare your shell command strings
whoami = Command('whoami')
who_i_am = `whoami`
```

Comment: Also you should probably not do this*

Answer (score -1):

## `repr()`

The `backtick` (`) operator **[was removed](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax.html#backticks)** in `Python 3`. It is confusingly similar to a single quote, and hard to type on some keyboards. Instead of the `backtick`, use the equivalent built-in function [`repr()`](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax.html#backticks).

Comment: That is not the equivalent of bash backticks.