# Python subprocess return parameter

Tags: python, parameters, subprocess

What command must I use in Python to invoke a program and receive a parameter in return.

Not a return "OK" or "not OK", but a returning identifier from the program that was invoked.

I am using subprocess.call, but I know that not works.

I am using Python 2.4.4.

Comment: use `subrocess.check_output` and write answer to stdout/stderr

Comment: Why are you still using Python 2.4.4?

Comment: Do you want to get the subprocess output (what you usually see in the terminal if you run it)? @m.wasowski: [there is no `subprocess.check_output()` in Python 2.4 though it is simple to define one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2924310/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may receive a result and pass a parameter. Terminology is not correct :)

Process returns a result of invocation. It would be 0 (success) or not zero (error condition).

Subprocess.Popen() is for your needs. Pass input to STDIN and get output from STDOUT. Called process must drop their results to STDOUT. Or use another IPC.