# python formatting return value of subprocess

Tags: subprocess, python-2.6

I am attempting on Python 2.6.6 to get the routing table of a system (for a interface) into a python list to parse;  but I cannot seem to solve why the entire result is stored into one variable.

The loop seems to iterate over one characters at a time, while the behavior I wanted was one line at a time.

what I get is one character; short example below...

```
1
0
.
2
4
3
```

what I'd like line to return; so I can run other commands against each line..

```
10.243.186.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
10.243.188.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
10.243.184.0    10.243.186.1    255.255.255.128 UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Here is the code below...

```
def getnet(int):
    int = 'eth0' ####### for testing only
    cmd = ('route -n | grep ' + int)
    routes = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    routes, err = routes.communicate()
    for line in routes:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

`routes` in your case is a bytestring that contains the *entire* output from the shell command. `for character in astring` statement produces one character at a time as the example in your question demonstrates. To get lines as a list of strings instead, call `lines = all_output.splitlines()`:

```
from subprocess import check_output

lines = check_output("a | b", shell=True, universal_newlines=True).splitlines()
```

Here's [a workaround if your Python version has no `check_output()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2924457/4915673). If you want to read one line at a time while the process is still running, see [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4915673).

You could try to use `os`, `ctypes` modules, to get the info instead of grepping the output of an external command.