# Python 2.6 : piping bash commands containing python variables(inside python script)

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, python-2.6

I want to run the below bash command from my python script:

```
stat --printf='%U%G%a' /tmp/file1.csv &&md5sum /tmp/file1.csv |awk '{print $1}'
```

I have done it using `subprocess.Popen` as below:

```
Command=subprocess.Popen(["stat --printf='%U%G%a' file1.csv &&md5sum file1.csv|awk '{print $1}'"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

But instead of hard coding the filename I need to pass a python variable. I tried

```
filevar="/tmp/file.csv"
Command=subprocess.Popen(["stat --printf='%U%G%a' filevar &&md5sum filevar|awk '{print $1}'"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

But the above code is not working.

I have been through all the answers related to `How to pass a python variable to subprocess`

The best answer I got till now is [piping python variable value to bash script (inside python script)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227351)

Based on this I tried:

```
Command=subprocess.Popen(["stat","--printf='%U%G%a'",filevar],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Which works great.  But when I try to include more commands like `md5sum` it throws error.

```
Command=subprocess.Popen(["stat","--printf='%U%G%a'",filevar,"&&","md5sum",filevar],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Please suggest how this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support spaces and other shell meta-characters, use [`pipes.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pipes
from subprocess import check_output

path = "/path/to/file.csv"
output = check_output("stat --printf='%U%G%a' {path} && md5sum {path}"
                      .format(path=pipes.quote(path))
                      + "|awk '{print $1}'", shell=True)
```

To get `check_output()` on Python 2.6, see [What's a good equivalent to python's subprocess.check_call that returns the contents of stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2924457/4279)

Note: `pipes.quote()` is not bullet-proof. Don't pass `path` to the shell unless it comes from a trusted source otherwise you risk an arbitrary shell command being executed ([shell injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection)).

As an alternative, you could [use `plumbum` to emulate the pipeline](http://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from plumbum.cmd import stat, md5sum, awk  # $ pip install plumbum

path = "/path/to/file.csv"
stat["--printf=%U%G%a", path]()
output = (md5sum[path] | awk['{print $1}'])()
```

See [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Depending on your case, it might make sense to implement the command in pure Python without external commands.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks a lot , I used plumbum to execute the commands

Comment: @rdm_ check whether you need to remove quotes around `--printf` value.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Popen` you simply pass a string to the function. So you could use string formatting to put the correct variable in there:

```
filevar="/tmp/file.csv"
Command=subprocess.Popen(["stat --printf='%U%G%a' %(filevar) &&md5sum filevar|awk '{print $1}'" % {"filevar": filevar}],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

Comment: thanks @datosh, but im getting the below error using the above command `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linuxx.py", line 8, in <module>
    Command=subprocess.Popen(["stat --printf='%U%G%a' %(filevar) &&md5sum filevar|awk '{print $1}'" % {"filevar": filevar}],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
ValueError: unsupported format character 'U' (0x55) at index 16` . Please suggest.