# What is the Python equivalent of Perl's backticks?

Tags: python, perl, terminal, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of Backticks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410976/equivalent-of-backticks-in-python)

When I want to write directly to the command prompt in Perl, I can do something like this:

Perl File **test.pl**:

```
$directory = `dir`;  
print $directory;
```

Which would output something like..

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\joslim\Desktop>perl test.pl
>
> Volume in drive C has no label. 
>   Volume Serial Number is EC37-EB31
>
> Directory of C:\Documents and
>   Settings\joslim\Desktop
>   (and a listing of all the files..)

Can I do this in Python? I've searched around but have had no luck.

Also, can you tell me what this is called? I'm sure there's a more technical term than "writing directly to the command prompt"...

Comment: Things like `dir` or `move` really shouldn't be done this way. There are cross-platform modules available in the standard library!

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60STRING%60

Comment: Marked as duplicate of what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are referring to in Perl is the backtick operator, which also behaves identically in PHP.

What you are looking to achieve is to execute a command line operation.

The equivalent in Python of the backtick operator, and how to run a command line program and retrieve the output, has been answered in: [Equivalent of Backticks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410976/equivalent-of-backticks-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent is [`commands.getoutput`](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html#commands.getoutput).  So for your example:

```
import commands
directory = commands.getoutput("dir")
print directory
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I see it's been deprecated and I'm to use the subprocess module now.