# How to store the result of an executed shell command in a variable in python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I need to store the result of a shell command that I executed in a variable, but I couldn't get it working. I tried like:

```
import os    

call = os.system("cat syscall_list.txt | grep f89e7000 | awk '{print $2}'")
print call
```

But it prints the result in terminal and prints the value of call as zero, possibly indicating as success. How to get the result stored in a variable?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410976/equivalent-of-backticks-in-python

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module instead:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("cat syscall_list.txt | grep f89e7000 | awk '{print $2}'", shell=True)
```

Edit: this is new in Python 2.7. In earlier versions this should work (with the command rewritten as shown below):

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '/f89e7000/ {print $2}', 'syscall_list.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

---

As a side note, you can rewrite

```
cat syscall_list.txt | grep f89e7000
```

To

```
grep f89e7000 syscall_list.txt
```

And you can even replace the entire statement with a single `awk` script:

```
awk '/f89e7000/ {print $2}' syscall_list.txt
```

Leading to:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['awk', '/f89e7000/ {print $2}', 'syscall_list.txt'])
```

Comment: I am using python 2.6.6 and it gives me error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
`

Comment: @user567879, You are right. This function was added in Python 2.7. I'll edit in a method for Python 2.6.

Comment: What if i need to pass a python variable as an argument to the executed shell command?

Comment: @user567879: Just do it how you would normally put a variable in a list, i.e. `['awk', '/f89e7000/ {print $2}', filename]`, and pass that to Popen().

Answer (score 20):

In python 3 you can use

```
import subprocess as sp
output = sp.getoutput('whoami --version')
print (output)

``
```

Answer (score 13):

os.popen works for this. popen - opens a pipe to or from command. The return value is an open file object connected to the pipe, which can be read. split('\n') converts the output to list

```
import os
list_of_ls = os.popen("ls").read().split('\n')
print list_of_ls
```

```
import os
list_of_call = os.popen("cat syscall_list.txt | grep f89e7000 | awk '{print $2}'").read().split('\n')
print list_of_call
```

Answer (score 11):

[commands.getstatusoutput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) would work well for this situation. (Deprecated since Python 2.6)

```
import commands
print(commands.getstatusoutput("cat syscall_list.txt | grep f89e7000 | awk '{print $2}'"))
```

Comment: The link doesn't work any more and this is removed in 3.x See https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html