# call linux command within python

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system, hardlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of Backticks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410976/equivalent-of-backticks-in-python)

I am looking for the best way to run a terminal command (ls -l) within Python. I have read about subprocess but I do not understand it fully, if someone could try and make me understand what is happening I would be grateful. I need to use the ls -l command to retrieve a hard link number which is != 1 and then save this number to match it against a directory number elsewhere. For now I would just like to know how to grab the hard link number and save it to a variable using subprocess (or a better method if there is one).

Here is the code I have used so far: 
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
#tool that resolves time machine directories 

import os

#create output file 
os.chdir("/home/sean/Desktop")
hard_link_number = open('hardLinkNumber.log', 'w')

#move into mounted backup (figure out how to remove xe2 etc)
os.chdir("/mnt/Backups.backupdb/stuart dent\xe2\x80\x99s MacBook Pro/2010-08-10-160859/MAc")

#find hard link data 
print>>hard_link_number, os.system("ls -la")
hard_link_number.close()
```

os.system("ls -la") outputs the information I require but it will not save it to the file I have created. I read elsewhere that os.system will not output data.

Comment: subprocess is the answer so I guess you'll have to take the time to understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) (specifically the `st_nlink` attribute).

*Edit:* To paraphrase [jwz](http://www.jwz.org/): Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll parse the output of `ls -l`." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `file` object to `stdout` in `subprocess.call()` and the output will be saved to that file:

```
In [26]: import subprocess

In [27]: with open("data.txt","w") as f:
    subprocess.call("ls -la",stdout=f,shell=True)
   ....:
```

Comment: You can't pass a `list` and have `shell=True`

Comment: Try it, with and without `shell=True`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary [Because](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen): [With `shell=True`] "If *args* is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself."

Comment: Quoting the docs _The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence._

Comment: `subprocess.check_output` is probably a simpler replacement for his existing code—it pretty much does exactly what he hoped `os.system` would, without having to understand `stdout` redirection or anything. Also, why use `shell=True` here? Instead of `os.system('ls -la')`, just `subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-la'])`, and nothing else needs to change. (Of course melpomene's answer is a better way to do what the OP actually _wants_.)