# Getting terminal output of a command from python

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I've tried to write a function that includes bash command. I want to assign the output of the command to variable in my python 
I mean, the function gitCheck find the directory of my git Repository and assign it to gitRep but It gives me only 0. Is there anyone to know how could I do that ? Thanks in advance

```
def gitCheck():
reference_repositories_path="cat $HOME/.git_reference_repositories | sed 's/GIT_REFERENCES_PATH=//'"
gitRep=os.system(reference_repositories_path)
print gitRep
```

**output** 
should be `/home/gwapps/Desktop/GIT_REFERENCE_REPOSITORIES`
but it gives me `0`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exit status. According to `os.system()` [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait().
>
> ...
>
> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function.

So, if you want to retrieve the output of the command, use `subprocess` module. There are tons of examples here on SO, e.g.:

- [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)
- [Equivalent of Bash Backticks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410976/equivalent-of-backticks-in-python)