# python equivalent of qx in perl-user/password prompt included

Tags: python

In Perl, if I have execute a script and pass a password to it programatically, I would do this:

```
my $result = qx { "Calling some script which prompts for a user and  password" <<EOF
administrator
password
EOF
};
```

It executes the following while capturing its output:

```
/bin/sh -c ' "Calling some script which prompts for a user and  password" <<EOF
administrator
password
EOF
'
```

May I know the equivalent of this in Python?

Comment: For us Python people: Please explain what this Perl code is doing. What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: `qx` is perl's "execute this" - it's identical to shell backticks. Runs the command and captures the _output_ in `$result`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of Backticks in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410976/equivalent-of-backticks-in-python)

Comment: @Sobrique Thanks. But how is the script in the question "pass a password"?

Comment: Don't know - I don't actually think that would work to pass a password to something anyway. Most things that take a password don't let you 'pipe' through them on `STDIN` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If I udnerstand your question correctly, you're trying to start an external script within its own process, and send that script some data - a password - via its standard input.

In Python, this is done using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. This module runs external scripts and has a `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` parameters.

For example, suppose that the script is `md5sum`. You would like to send it the password `secret`:

```python
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> p = sp.Popen('md5sum', stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
>>> p.communicate(input="secret")                   # <-- Your password
('5ebe2294ecd0e0f08eab7690d2a6ee69  -\n', '')       # <-- Process output
```

`p.communicate()` returns an (`stdout`, `stderr`) tuple, which is useful for processing the script output.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475367/51197) useful.