# A.py to invoke B.py, after B.py is finished how can I let B return a list to A

Tags: python, python-2.7

In A.py, I use os.system( "B.py %s" % searchPath ) to invoke B.py. B.py will do some logical operations and get some data.

How can I let B.py returns these data to A.py, what should I do in B.py?

Comment: why not `import B` and use `B.some_function()` inside `A`?

Comment: hiro protagonist, thank you and I will try your idea(at the very beginning, I only know os.system('B.py') this way, so I ignore all other possibility..

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways:

1. write and read file;
2. use Queue;
3. as hiro protagonist says, import B into A and call B's functions.

Update:

Queue example: check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html?highlight=queue

Example of how to wait for enqueued tasks to be completed from above link:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: Can you give me a simple example about 2.Queue, I am not sure how to do.

Comment: updated. From I guess, you should take No. 3 to do it, you are new to python.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot directly invoke B from A you can consider the following:

1. Use `stdout` and JSON. I have used this technique to integrate applications that are written in different languages. `B.py` will do all the calculations, store them in a `dict` or `list` structure and when it is finished call [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). The advantage of this is that you can also do error/warning handling by returnring structures like `{"status": "OK", "warning": "Could not find XYZ... skipped"}`
2. Use an intermediate stage. This is preferred when `B.py` returns a large amount of data. The medium can be a temporary file or a database. You can also combine both! and make `B.py` to create a database in a file ([`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html))
3. If the data that you return are minimal, you can consider using exit status only to indicate success or failure...

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at [subprocesses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). The solution to your question would look something like

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["B.py", searchpath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print "program output:", out
```

For a similar question:
[Equivalent of Bash Backticks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410976/equivalent-of-backticks-in-python)

Comment: I am not so clear, When I invoke B.py it will follow 2 parameters looks like 'B.py -f searchPath' and '-f' is permanent and searchPath is flexible. Is this method also possible for my question? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question is a little bit generic.
You can use an  IPC method to pass data between 2 processes (or 2 different runs of 2 scripts which is the same):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Usually the more basic ones are piping stdout-stdin or using a file.
For example the Popen object of the subprocess module has a communicate method which is useful to get the data:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

```
output=`dmesg | grep hda`
# becomes
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```