# Store value of os.system or os.popen

Tags: python, bash, operating-system

I want to grep the error's out of a log file and save the value as an error. When I use:

```
errors = os.system("cat log.txt | grep 'ERROR' | wc -l")
```

I get the return code that the command worked or not. When I use:

```
errors = os.popen("cat log.txt | grep 'ERROR' | wc -l")
```

I get what the command is trying to do.

When I run this in the command line I get 3 as thats how many errors there are.

Can anyone suggest another way in Python that will allow me to save the value of this bash command?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`popen` is deprecated. Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead. For example, in your case:

```
p1 = Popen(["cat", "log.txt"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "ERROR"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

First open a pipe using popen as you did.

```
p = os.popen("cat log.txt | grep 'ERROR' | wc -l")
```

Now just access the pipe like a normal file:

```
output = p.readline()
```

This will be a string so you'll still have to do some additional parsing, but that shouldn't be a problem.

EDIT:  Ok, it seems that from Python 2.6 onwards, os.popen is deprecated.  I thus defer my answer to whoever answered correctly using subprocess.Popen instead.  Thanks for that guys.

Comment: I've provided possible alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817416/store-value-of-os-system-or-os-popen/2817565#2817565

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for:

```
grep -c 'ERROR' log.txt
```

Generally for spawning a subprocess you need to use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. There are plenty example, I'm sure you wouldn't get lost.

Comment: The bash is fine, I want to save the output to the variable in Python

Answer (score 0):

How many `'ERROR'` in the file:

```
nerrors = open('log.txt').read().count('ERROR') # put whole file in memory
```

How many lines that contain `'ERROR'`:

```
nerrors = sum(1 for line in open('log.txt') if 'ERROR' in line) # line at a time
```

If you must use the literal bash line then in Python 2.7+:

```
from subprocess import check_output as qx
nerrors = int(qx("cat your_file.txt | grep 'ERROR' | wc -l", shell=True))
```

See [Capturing system command output as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236737/capturing-system-command-output-as-a-string/236909#236909) for an implementation of `check_output()` for Python < 2.7.