# running shell commands with gnu clisp

Tags: lisp, stream, clisp

I'm trying to create a "system" command for clisp that works like this

```
(setq result (system "pwd"))

;;now result is equal to /my/path/here
```

I have something like this:

```
(defun system (cmd)
 (ext:run-program :output :stream))
```

But, I am not sure how to transform a stream into a string. I've reviewed the hyperspec and google more than a few times.

edit: working with Ranier's command and using with-output-to-stream,

```
(defun system (cmd)
  (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (ext:run-program cmd :output stream)))
```

And then trying to run `grep`, which is in my path...

```
[11]> (system "grep")

*** - STRING: argument #<OUTPUT STRING-OUTPUT-STREAM> should be a string, a
      symbol or a character
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead.
ABORT          :R2      Abort main loop
Break 1 [12]> :r2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

Version 2:

```
(defun copy-stream (in out)
   (loop for line = (read-line in nil nil)
         while line
         do (write-line line out)))

(defun system (cmd)
  (with-open-stream (s1 (ext:run-program cmd :output :stream))
    (with-output-to-string (out)
      (copy-stream s1 out))))


[6]> (system "ls")
"#.emacs#
Applications
..."
```

Comment: question: what does the :output indicate? is that a named parameter syntax?

Comment: :output is a parameter that sets where the output will be directed to. in this it'll be directed to a stream.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [CLISP documentation on `run-program`](http://clisp.cons.org/impnotes/shell.html#run-prog), the `:output` argument should be one of

- `:terminal` - writes to the terminal
- `:stream` - *creates* and returns an *input stream* from which you can read
- a *pathname designator* - writes to the designated file
- `nil` - ignores the output

If you're looking to collect the output into a string, you'll have to use a read-write copying loop to transfer the data from the returned stream to a string. You already have [`with-output-to-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm) in play, per Rainer's suggestion, but instead of providing that output stream to `run-program`, you'll need to write to it yourself, copying the data from the *input stream* returned by `run-program`.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking specifically about clisp. I'll add here that
if you are using Clozure CL then you can also easily run os subprocesses.

Some examples:

```
;;; Capture the output of the "uname" program in a lisp string-stream
;;; and return the generated string (which will contain a trailing
;;; newline.)
? (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (run-program "uname" '("-r") :output stream))
;;; Write a string to *STANDARD-OUTPUT*, the hard way.
? (run-program "cat" () :input (make-string-input-stream "hello") :output t)
;;; Find out that "ls" doesn't expand wildcards.
? (run-program "ls" '("*.lisp") :output t)
;;; Let the shell expand wildcards.
? (run-program "sh" '("-c" "ls *.lisp") :output t)
```

Do a search for run-program in the CCL docs located here: http://ccl.clozure.com/ccl-documentation.html

There are a couple nice Lisp ways of doing this in this stackoverflow answer: [Making a system call that returns the stdout output as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236737/making-a-system-call-that-returns-the-stdout-output-as-a-string)  Once again, Rainer to the rescue. Thanks Ranier.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter one

```
(defun system(cmd)
  (ext:shell (string cmd)))

> (system '"cd ..; ls -lrt; pwd")
```