# write python script to run the shell script?

Tags: python, shell

I run the svn status got the modified files :

```
  svn status
  ?       .settings
  ?       .buildpath
  ?       .directory
  A       A.php
  M       B.php
  D       html/C.html
  M       html/D.fr
  M       api/E.api
  M       F.php
  ..
```

After I want to keep all of these files

`zcvf MY.tar.gz all files that svn stat display` 
(not include ? just M,A,D)

My idea is to create the python script can run the shell,because right now to do this I just copy the file name one by one.

`zcvf MY.tar.gz all the files that we run svn stat`

Anybody could guide how to do this or some related tutorial? But if you think it `difficult than copy && paste` I will ignore my trying?

thanks

Comment: Redirect the the output of "svn status" then parse the output file using Python. Where is the problem?

Comment: if you can, do it with the shell..Why the need to write a Python script?

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would use python for this if you can do it in a single line of code in the shell.

```
svn status | grep "^[AMD]" | sed 's/^.\{8\}//' | xargs zcvf My.tar.gz
```

I used `grep` to only select lines that are modified, if you want all files that svn status lists (also those that are added / deleted) you can leave that part out. I've used `sed` here to delete the first part of every line, I'm sure there is an easier way to do that but I can't think of one right now.

Comment: you said "I've used sed here to delete the first part of every line" why?

Comment: Because "svn status" gives lines like `M       file.txt`. You are only interested in the `file.txt` part.

Comment: Instead of `sed` you could also use `cut -b9`

Answer (score 1):

Once you figure out your command as a string you can just call it with subprocess

[subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

This module spawns called processes and allows you to control them. From there its up to you.

Comment: I don't need examples :L you should edit and add the examples to someones post

Answer (score 0):

[`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) is the Pythonic way, but using a small bash one-liner could be a shorter idea.

#### Bash one-liner

```
svn status | egrep "^  M" | awk '{s=s $2 " "} END {print "tar cvfz MY.tar "s}'
```

#### Subprocess

```
import subprocess as sp
p=sp.Popen('svn status', shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, 
                                     stderr=sp.PIPE).communicate()[0]
files=[]
for line in p:
     if line.strip().find('M')==0:
          files.append(line.split(' ')[1].strip())

files=' '.join(files)
sp.Popen('tar cvfz MY.tar.gz '+files, shell=True).communicate()
```

Comment: "grep M" is not correct, it'll also select lines like `"A       MyNewFile.txt"`

Comment: Fixed to an egrep regex pattern.

Comment: In your new python code you make exactly the same mistake. You shouldn't compare to the result of `line.find('M')` to `!=-1` but to `==0` instead. Your python code will also fail for files with spaces in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and [`check_call()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call, check_output as qx

filenames = [line[8:] # extract filename
             for line in qx(['svn', 'status']).splitlines()
             if not line.startswith('?')] # exclude files that are not under VC
check_call(['tar', 'cvfz', 'MY.tar.gz'] + filenames)
```

On Python < 2.7 see [`check_output()` recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236737/making-a-system-call-that-returns-the-stdout-output-as-a-string/236909#236909).