# Python subprocess readlines()?

Tags: python, subprocess

So I'm trying to move away from os.popen to subprocess.popen as recommended by the user guide.  The only trouble I'm having is I can't seem to find a way of making readlines() work.

So I used to be able to do

```
list = os.popen('ls -l').readlines()
```

But I can't do

```
list = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l']).readlines()
```

Comment: would rather do `list = subprocess.call(['ls','-l']).readlines()
`

Comment: That's wrong -- `call` only returns the returncode, not the output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924310/whats-a-good-equivalent-to-pythons-subprocess-check-call-that-returns-the-conte

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With `subprocess.Popen`, use `communicate` to read and write data:

```
out, err = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Then you can always split the string from the processes' `stdout` with `splitlines()`.

```
out = out.splitlines()
```

Comment: Thought this was meant to be the "nice new way" of doing it. Thanks for the answer, I'll set it when the timeout reaches.  I mihg tjust stick to popen.

Comment: The problem with `communicate` is that you get all of the output at once, which in the case of a non-recursive `ls` is not likely a problem. By using the `stdout` member, you can read line-by-line (think `find`).

Comment: @FredFoo That's right... I've created a little thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858329/custom-popen-communicate-method-gives-wrong-output) in order to try to address what you're mentioning in your comment... it's not working well yet though :)

Answer (score 39):

```
ls = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = ls.stdout.readlines()
```

or, if you want to read line-by-line (maybe the other process is more intensive than `ls`):

```
for ln in ls.stdout:
    # whatever
```

Comment: This approach is preferable to the accepted answer as it allows one to read through the output as the sub process produces it.

Comment: You need to iterate differently over `stdout`.

Comment: **Don't do that**, the Python3 documentation states the following: "Warning: Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process. "

Answer (score 13):

[Making a system call that returns the stdout output as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236737/making-a-system-call-that-returns-the-stdout-output-as-a-string/236909#236909):

```
lines = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l']).splitlines()
```

Comment: Nice, I guess it's not widely known because it's Python 2.7+ only.

Comment: @agf: follow the link there is an adaption for older Python versions.

Comment: I know, I already followed both links you posted (and upvoted each post). I was just surprised that I didn't know about this convenience function until I saw it was 2.7+.

Comment: This one is the recommended  solution, if you are using 2.7+

Answer (score 3):

```
list = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].splitlines()
```

straight from the `help(subprocess)`

Comment: That's not a list of lines, it's a single multi-line string.

Answer (score 3):

A more detailed way of using subprocess.

```py
# Set the command
command = "ls -l"

# Setup the module object
proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
                    shell=True,   
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# Communicate the command   
stdout_value,stderr_value = proc.communicate()

# Once you have a valid response, split the return output    
if stdout_value:
    stdout_value = stdout_value.split()
```