# executing a python script from another python script

Tags: python

I have a script a.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def foo(arg1, arg2):
    return int(arg1) + int(arg2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   print foo(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])`
```

I now want to make a script that can run the first script and write the output of a.py to a file with some arguments as well. I want to make the automate_output(src,arglist) generate some kind of an output that I can write to the outfile :

```
import sys

def automate_output(src,  arglist):
    return ""


def print_to_file (src, outfile, arglist):
    print "printing to file %s" %(outfile)
    out = open(outfile, 'w')
    s = open(src, 'r')

    for line in s:
        out.write(line)
    s.close()

    out.write(" \"\"\"\n Run time example: \n") 
    out.write(automate(src, arglist))
    out.write(" \"\"\"\n")
    out.close()


try: 
    src = sys.argv[1]
    outfile = sys.argv[2]
    arglist = sys.argv[3:]
    automate(src, arglist)
    print_to_file(src,outfile,arglist)  
except:
    print "error"
    #print "usage : python automate_runtime.py scriptname outfile args"
```

I have tried searching around, but so far I do not understand how to pass arguments by using os.system with arguments. I have also tried doing :

```
import a
a.main()
```

There I get a NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Update : 
I researched some more and found subprocess and I'm quite close to cracking it now it seems.
The following code does work, but I would like to pass args instead of manually passing '2' and '3'
    src = 'bar.py'
    args = ('2' , '3')
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', src,  '2' , '3'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print proc.communicate()[0]

Comment: Actually, given what you did there, you'll get an `ImportError: No module named py` due to doing `import a.py` rather than `import a`. And the reason you get the `NameError` is because the name 'main' is not defined in the module `a`.

Comment: However, I don't understand why main is not defined? I do have  if __name__ == "__main__":

Comment: If you can't see what's wrong, please read the Python tutorial; if you understand it, you'll understand what's wrong here.

Comment: Use argument unpacking `Popen(['python', 'bar.py',  *args])`

Comment: @sdolan: tuple unpacking doesn't work in this case, instead use `['a', 'b'] + list(args)`.

Comment: proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', src,  list(args)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

does not work either : TypeError: execv() arg2 must contain only strings

Comment: @Arnab Datta: compare: `['a', 'b'] + list(args)` and `['a', 'b', list(args)]`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : yes, now I do.. no sleep for 2 days made me blind..Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a function, it's an `if` statement:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

If you want a main function, define one:

```
import sys

def main():
   print foo(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])`
```

Then just call it if you need to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.main()` has nothing to do with `if __name__=="__main__"` block. The former calls a function named `main()` from `a` module, the latter executes its block if current module name is `__main__` i.e., when a module is called as a script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# a.py
def func():
    print repr(__name__)

if __name__=="__main__":
    print "as a script",
    func()
```

Compare a module executed as a script and a function called from the imported module:

```
$ python a.py
as a script '__main__'

$ python -c "import a; print 'via import',; a.func()"
via import 'a'
```

See [section Modules in the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

To get output from the subprocess you could use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#subprocess.check_output) function:

```
import sys
from subprocess import check_output as qx

args = ['2', '3']
output = qx([sys.executable, 'bar.py'] + args)
print output
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name check_output

Comment: @Arnab Datta: `check_output()` is new in Python 2.7. On older version you could use [`cmd_output()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236737/making-a-system-call-that-returns-the-stdout-output-as-a-string/236909#236909)